# How can I get service principal properties using Azure SDK for .Net

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, .net-standard, azure-sdk-.net

I need to get application display name by service principal id in UWP C# project. I found sample [Getting started on managing service principals using C#](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/aad-dotnet-manage-service-principals), but this sample based on Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent, Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent and Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent, which are deprecated. Any other ways to get appId (except http request) I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

*Before installing the NuGet packages, use the latest .Net framework in order to resolve few of the deprecated issues.*

*For these deprecated packages

```
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent
Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent
```

*Microsoft has provided alternate packages and the dependencies for the packages.*

*Use the below highlighted alternate packages
For `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` and `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent` use `Azure.ResourceManager`*

[image]

*Azure.ResourceManager*

[image]

*Azure.ResourceManager*

[image]

[image]

*And the below package is not deprecated* `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer, RajeshM. But I had read migration info of deprecated packages and hadn't found how to create objects of IServicePrincipal (which is defined in non-deprecated package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent). In deprecated packages IServicePrincipal was a result of calls: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Configure()?.Authenticate(...)?ServicePrincipals. What is alternate way to get IServicePrincipal using Azure.ResourceManager?

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent 1.38.1 is not deprecated and it was published in April 2022.